# Android TV how to change detailsFragment data when I click action button?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I want to change description in the `fullWidthDetailsOverviewRowPresenter` when I click action `button`, how to do it? I can change data, however how to refresh the `view`?

[image]

For example, when I click "BUY$9.99", text in the red box will change.

Comment: Could you provide more details with code or screen shot as this much description is not enough to understand what is your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this line:

`detailsOverviewRow.setItem(newItem);`

in your `DetailsFragment`, where you may have something like this:

```
    private DetailsOverviewRow detailsOverviewRow;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        detailsOverviewRow = new DetailsOverviewRow(oldItem);
        SectionDetailsPresenter detailsPresenter =
                new SectionDetailsPresenter(new  SectionDetailsDescriptionPresenter());

        detailsPresenter.setOnActionClickedListener(new OnActionClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onActionClicked(Action action) {
                if (action.getId() == ACTION_BUY) {
                    Object newItem = oldItem;
                    newItem.setDescription("new description");
                    detailsOverviewRow.setItem(newItem);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The `newItem` is the `oldItem`you used to create an instance of `DetailsOverviewRow`, but with the description attribute changed.

Once you set a new item for your `DetailsOverviewRow`, the description presenter (`SectionDetailsDescriptionPresenter` in this sample) will be called again, and it will set the `newItem` description attribute in the red box you were asking for.